# Angular Reactive Form Can't assign default date value to datepicker

Tags: angular

I am trying to assigned a custom date to the angular app datepicker, but no date value is showing.

Originally, my html datepicker code is this

```
<div class="form-contrl-margin-bottom">
            <input type="date" class="form-control form-cntrl" formControlName="myStartDt"> 
              
          </div>
```

In my ts code, I set the value with this

```
this.myForm.setValue({
  myStartDt: formatDate('01/01/2021', 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en')
});
```

When I set the formGroup, I tried to test and set the default value but it is not working

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
   this.myForm = this.fb.group({

        myStartDt: [formatDate('01/01/2021', 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en')]
});
}
```

In the html, I tried add a value tag like the following but it is not working

```
            <input type="date" class="form-control form-cntrl" formControlName="myStartDt"
            value="{{searchParams?.startDt | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}"
            > 
              
          </div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no build in valueAccessor for date input control in angular, It would not set value on input element.

Create custom ControlValueAccessor to support native input element.

First create directive then set selector name to input[type=date]

**directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=date]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateInputConverter),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class DateInputConverter implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @HostListener('blur', []) onTouched: any = () => { };
  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onChange: any = () => { };

  private valueType: 'value' | 'valueAsDate' = 'value';

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) { this.onTouched = fn; }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this.onChange = (event: any) => fn(event.target[this.valueType])
  }

  writeValue(value: Date | string) {
    this.valueType = typeof value === 'string' ? 'value' : 'valueAsDate';
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.valueType, value);
  }
}
```

component.html

```
    <label for="date-string">Regular string value</label>
    <input [formControl]="dateStringControl" type="date" id="date-string" />

    <label for="date-object">Date object value with directive help</label>
    <input [formControl]="dateObjectControl" type="date" id="date-object" />
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uheqy7)

Reference: https://coryrylan.com/blog/using-html5-date-input-with-date-objects-and-angular#form-control-directive

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. I am not sure if you have defined `myStartDt` as a formControl or not, but the place where you define the form and formcontrols right, there you can set the default value. Something like this:

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
  myStartDt: new FormControl(formatDate('01/01/2021', 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en'), [Validators.required])
})
```

The above method should set the value to the formControl as soon as the form is initiated.